# Vertical Pagination of Divs

Tags: css, html

What I want to do is setup multiple div's that each contain the contents of an entire page. Each div should be centered in the viewport and fill it entirely. Each successive div should be evenly spaced vertically based on the variable height of the viewport. For example say I have a view of 800x600 then each div should be this size and stacked. So, if I scrolled down exactly 600px I would only see page 2 div, 1200px I'd only see page 3 div. I don't have any code or example to share and my exhausted searches have turned up nothing of this sort. Is this possible with just css?

Comment: you might need to dynamically resize the divs based on the browser window size...here's something i found that might help: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to give your `html`, `body` & `div`s a `height: 100%;`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KMMjv/

Comment: As stated this works fine on its own. However I am trying to use the HTML5 Boilerplate and when I do, this setup breaks. Any ideas what might be causing this from that template?

Answer (score 0):

Because this would vary depending on the size of the user's browser window you would need to JavaScript to detect screen height and position them accordingly.  Although you could set the height of each div with just CSS (`height: 100%;`) you would need to set the `top` with JS.

Here is a working JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ogokef/edit#preview

Answer (score 0):

Use the following units:
vh for viewport height
vw for viewport width

```
html, body {
            height: 100vh;
           }
      div {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%; /* you can use 100vw too, but for height it must be vh */
          }
```

Comment: vh sucks when using images

Comment: You should use class for images then.